# Can't show window from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4

I have several threads that need to work with window. Here's thread definition:

```
class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, id, window, mutex):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.window = window
        self.mutex = mutex
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("load_message_input()"), self.window, QtCore.SLOT("show_input()"))

    def run(self):
        self.mutex.lock()
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("load_message_input()"))
        self.connect(self.window, QtCore.SIGNAL("got_message(QString)"), self.print_message)
        self.window.input_finished.wait(self.mutex)
        self.mutex.unlock()

    def print_message(self, str):
        print "Thread %d: %s" % (self.id, str)
```

And here's window definition:

```
class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.last_message = None

        self.setModal(True)
        self.message_label = QtGui.QLabel(u"Message")
        self.message_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.dialog_buttons = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.dialog_buttons.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.dialog_buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.message_label)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.message_input)
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.dialog_buttons)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.input_finished = QtCore.QWaitCondition()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_input(self):
        self.exec_()

    def on_accepted(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("got_message(QString)"), self.message_input.text())
        self.input_finished.wakeOne()
```

And here's main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
    threads = []
    window = test_qdialog.MyDialog()

    for i in range(5):
        thread = MyThread(i, window, mutex)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    for t in threads:
        t.wait()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can't figure out why window isn't shown when executing the script.

**Update**:
For some reason other threads don't stop on line with `self.mutex.lock()`. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code:

- If you want a `QThread` to use slots you need to *create* an event loop for it (which is easy, just call `QThread.exec_`), but `QThread`s with event loops needs to be coded differently (next I'll post you an example)
- You need to connect `on_accepted` to `accepted` if you want to emit the messages, unless you use the auto-connect  features of Qt.
- If you want to use `QThread` first you need to start a `QApplication` so `for t in threads: t.wait()` can't be executed before the call to `QApplication.exec_` (in my example just removed it).
- The last but not less important issue: If you want your threads to consume resources exclusively you should think of a consumer-producer approach (the problem is that when you emit a signal every slot will get a copy of the data and if you try to block a thread with an event loop the application just freezes, to solve the problem of consumer-producer I pass an extra mutex to the signal of the message and *try* to lock it [never blocking!] to know if the thread con consume the event)

As promised there is an example of how to use event loops on `QThread`s:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):

    load_message_input = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, id, window):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.window = window
        self.load_message_input.connect(self.window.show_input)
        self.window.got_message.connect(self.print_message)
        self.started.connect(self.do_stuff)

    def run(self):
        print "Thread %d: %s" % (self.id,"running")
        self.exec_()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() 
    def do_stuff(self):
        print "Thread %d: %s" % (self.id,"emit load_message_input")
        self.load_message_input.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QString","QMutex")
    def print_message(self, msg, mutex):
        if mutex.tryLock():
            print "Thread %d: %s" % (self.id, msg)
        self.do_stuff()


class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    got_message = QtCore.pyqtSignal("QString","QMutex")    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.last_message = None

        self.setModal(True)
        self.message_label = QtGui.QLabel(u"Message")
        self.message_input = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.dialog_buttons = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.dialog_buttons.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.dialog_buttons.accepted.connect(self.on_accepted)
        self.dialog_buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.message_label)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.message_input)
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.dialog_buttons)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.input_finished = QtCore.QWaitCondition()   


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_input(self):
        print "showing input"
        window.show()
        window.setModal(True)    


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_accepted(self):
        print "emit: ", self.message_input.text()
        self.got_message.emit(self.message_input.text(), QtCore.QMutex())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
    threads = []
    window = MyDialog()

    for i in range(5):
        thread = MyThread(i, window)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    print "start app"
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: almost always the thread who receives the signal first will be the one with id 1.

My recommendation, do not use slots in your threads (which will make safe the use of mutex and wait-conditions) and implement a consumer-producer approach for the messages.

Comment: There are few things that I still don't understand. First, why do you invoke `do_stuff` again from `print_message`. And second, why do you transmit QMutex from QDialog? I think everytime when QDialog emits such signal QMutex object will be different.

Comment: I invoke `do_stuff` again to provide a processing loop, you can safety delete it if you want the threads to run only once. The mutex object is for exclusion in the handling of the message: only the the first thread who calls `QMutex.tryLock` obtains a value of `True` so only one thread consumes the message (which I supposed was what you want).

Comment: The problem here is that the same thread that requests window to show has to get message.

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting for the threads to exit, before calling app.exec_(). You should probably monitor the threads in a GUI idle loop or connect to the thread's finished() signal.